# search specific items from sql database using ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

i have crawled a website using Html Agility Pack i have the data stored in my SQL SERVER DB of the whole website i am making a thing like search engine whenever u write anything the name of item or just brand like HP it should display the data i have used like queries in my stored procedures but the problem i am facing is that when i search HP it just don't bring HP laptops but also all the items in my database which have HP in their name, can anyone tell me what can be the possible solution for this problem or some hint? like query is giving me all the items not just HP or should i have to crawl meta data of website as well? like google does that

Comment: Let's start by sharing the code in question, the data structure you are storing the data in, and the query you are issuing.

Comment: ambigious question